# Html and Javascript API Project

Tags: javascript

Hey I am having trouble importing the data using my javascript code using this API, can someone please help out and tell me how I can at least get the data into an array or anything... I tried debugging with Firebug but no luck in decoding the cryptic messages :

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type=button value="Basic 3D Bar Chart" onclick="basicBar()">
        Find website traffic.
        <br>
        Enter a website (no "www." but ending with ".com, .edu, etc."):
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="website">

        <input type="button" value="Graph Visits" onclick="getVisits(website.value)">

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function callScript(call) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', call);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function getVisits(website) {
    callScript("http://api.similarweb.com/Site/" + website + "/v1/visits?gr=monthly&start=1-2014&end=12-2014&md=false&Format=JSON&UserKey=da8e48657cc4d5393730df1d858c6a71&callback=parseData");
}

function parseData(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from Googling AJAX

Comment: I tried looking that up, but originally in the past this method of using a callScript function in Javascript worked well, surprisingly I just cant get the data to come in to my code. Firebug just stops and tells me there is an error

Comment: OK yes and using a knife to eat soup works. This doesn't mean you should not use a spoon

Comment: Or to put it more kindly, why not use a good tool if its there?

Comment: Or to put it less kindly... if you wrote this code in a professional context you would be fired on the spot

Comment: Nick, I kindly ask you to please help me fix this code and get the api's data into the javascript. Forgive me if I dont want to use AJAX, but I desire to use javascrip and learn why right now it doesn't workt!!! =]

Comment: AJAX is JavaScript. Read the native method link I provided if you want pure JavaScript.

Comment: Does anyone else have any solutions or explanations... Oka and Nick - thank you for your AJAX

Answer (score 0):

APIs typically return data, not scripts.

What you are really looking for is a set of technologies called [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

You need to `GET` and parse the data, in this case `JSON`, using an asynchronous request.

Here's an example in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), a popular JavaScript library, using the baseline [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/url/to/my/api',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',

  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is some documentation on the native methods.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for responding, but I rather stick to what I got so I can master this before even tackling AJAX, I understand that the script returns data - thus the data in my parseData function but this data is not coming in well - could you by any chance help with this?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. This is the proper way to pull from API endpoints. You shouldn't be hacking together scripts from JSON data. Just look at the [response](http://api.similarweb.com/Site/google.com/v1/visits?gr=monthly&start=1-2014&end=12-2014&md=false&Format=JSON&UserKey=da8e48657cc4d5393730df1d858c6a71&callback=parseData) from that API - It's not a script that you can execute.